# Cannot launch python via cmd

Tags: python-3.x, msix

Currently I'm working on a project to deliver apps via MSIX packaging including python as one of them. I've already created an msix package for the same with below settings :

[image: Python installation settings]

So the MSIX package displays the environment variables added to the system path

[image: Python MSIX package registry]

VHD has been mounted (staged) and registered on test machine, however I still cannot open python via cmd

[image: Cannot find python]

I'm a bit new to the MSIX packaging tech, so any help would be appreciated.

Users to be able to run python from cmd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files that are packaged and deployed with an MSIX run inside a container. This means that these files will not be "visible" by default to tools like cmd or Powershell.

You need to define an **appExecutionAlias** in your package manifest. The following SO question has more details:

- [How to run an MSIX installed application from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66700285/how-to-run-an-msix-installed-application-from-the-command-line/66704079#66704079)

If you're using the MSIX Packaging Tool or Visual Studio to build the package, you need to manually edit the AppXManifest.xml file and add the appExecutionAlias element.

If you're using other commercial tools, you probably have a GUI option to include and configure it.

Comment: Thanks a ton Bogdan, that worked like a charm.

Comment: Anytime. Don't forget the mark the question as answered if this worked for you.

Comment: Hi Bogdan, same has been done, thanks again for your help :)