# MSIX: Start other Application in Multiple-Application Package?

Tags: visual-studio, msix

So a Windows Application Packaging Project in Visual Studio can have references to multiple projects, which will be included in the package. One of those references/applications then gets defined as the entry point/startup application.

Is it possible to know where the *other* application in the package is located, so that I can start it from the entry point/startup application?

Hope this makes sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to programmatically launch your other application, right?

By design, the binaries from an installation folder of an MSIX folder are not directly accessible through their direct path. I know this is how we did it for Win32 applications, but for containerized ones things have changed.

The correct way to run an app, installed by an MSIX package, programmatically or from the command line is with the use of an **execution alias**. The following article contains more details about how an execution alias works and how you can define it in your package, no matter the tool you use to build the MSIX package.

[- App Execution Alias](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/msix-environment-variables.html)

Also, [here is a related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63404924/how-can-i-get-my-msix-installer-to-add-my-cli-application-binary-to-the-path/63446269#63446269) and [another similar one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66700285/how-to-run-an-msix-installed-application-from-the-command-line/66704079#66704079).